# Resize XHTML with window

Tags: css, xhtml, resize

I've done this in the past, but forgot how to do it.

How can I set a "master" container in css/xhtml and have the website resize with the browser window when resized?

For example, if I have a "master" container div of 500px by 500px and a user resizes their browser window, how can I get that container to resize with it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use `max-height` and `max-width` instead of `height` and `width`.

Comment: when I do it to all of the divs, it messes up the site. should it only be done to the master container? Thanks again

Comment: yeah only master container as block-level elements fit their container's width.

Comment: thanks... 
#page-container {
max-width:150%;
margin-top: 5%;
}

the site strethces out and fills the page... how do I condense it to a set width without losing my "resize" ?

Comment: 150% of body's width will always be larger than the body..! You're not obligated to use percentages.

Comment: thank you so much for that, it worked great.. I changed it to 90. I read that one should use em or % as opposed to px being that the high res devices today don't like px... is this false?

Comment: also, how do limit how far over the "resize" can go? if you resize the webpage to say 4 inches by 6 inches, the text gets all messed up as does the sidebar

Comment: you're welcome. I never use pixels so I guess it's right ^^ And you have min-height and min-width too.

Comment: #page-container {
max-width:90%;
min-width:50%;
margin-left: 5%;
margin-top: 2%;
}

It still doesn't limit how much over you can go :(

Comment: min-width isn't usually in percentage as if your block takes 90% it never takes 50%...

Comment: #page-container {
max-width:90%;
min-width:60px;
margin-left: 5%;
margin-top: 2%;
} it didn't fix it... is min-width what I should use to limit how much one can resize horizontally? Thanks thanks thanks

Comment: With your code a horizontal scrollbar should appear if viewport's width becomes smaller than 60px. Isn't it the case?

Comment: No scroll bar, it just contiually goes as far as it can go.

Comment: OKay, I clicked the check mark for you have answered my question http://jsfiddle.net/vU8bY/

Comment: It actually works. Do you have notice that 60px is far too smaller for displaying such content?

Comment: I'm a bit confused... I even changed 60px to 200px but it still "squeezes all of the text"

Comment: 200px TOO is too small -_- try at least 300px

Comment: #page-container {
max-width:90%;
min-width:300px;
margin-left: 5%;
margin-top: 2%;
} - still no luck :(

Comment: It works for me, maybe your font is too big to fit in 300px. And use margin:2% auto 0; to center.

Comment: cool, what does the "2%" do? I understand the concept of auto margin, but not the 2%. I'm using firefox btw, does that have anything to do with it

Comment: ...it's for your margin-top: 2%;

Comment: Okay, thank you for all of your help. Can you think of anything else as to why the min-width is still allowing for the website to be "squeezed"? I messed with the fonts and it didn't fix it. Otherwise, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to size your container using `%` rather than `px`.

This way it'll scale to fit the browser window as you resize it.

```
#container{
 width:90%;
}
```